# apple has rejected my iPhone app saying it must run on iPad as well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, app-store

I've just submitted my app to review (for the App-Store), and apple has rejected my app, saying the following:

> "On iPad, the application displays a
>   black screen and no content loads.
>   This review was conducted on iPad
>   running iOS 3.2.2 as well as iPhone 4
>   running iOS 4.1. A screenshot has been
>   attached for your reference. "

am i obligated to create an iPad version of my app? or maybe i've set some property "on" and made apple think i would like the app to work on iPad?

to be more clear,
i want my app to run on iPhone only.
is it possible? and if do, what need to be set (project properties? info.plist?) to mention that the app should run on iPhone only? so that apple will not test it on iPad...

appriciate your help.

Dror.

Comment: I think when they mean is it needs to work on the iPad using the iPhone emulation (the option with the 2x zoom), not that it needs to have a native iPad version.

Comment: "...displays a black screen....screenshot has been attached"  That's kind of a slap in the face, isn't it?

Comment: I imagine they are specifically talking about the iPhone app compatibility mode for the iPad. Basically, it has to at least _run_ on the iPad. It doesn't necessarily need to _be an iPad app_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note - this historic QA is 5+ years old.**

**All issues mentioned in the QA are no longer relevant in iOS development! Enjoy**

---

The problem is almost certainly that you (accidentally) made the app universal.

IF you made it universal, you MUST have both an iPad and iPhone version in there.

If you make the app normal, iPhone only, you do NOT have to (indeed, you can't) have an iPad version in there.

To be clear, Apple are talking about the "ACTUAL" iPad version. Of course, your iPhone app will run using the "blow up mode" on an iPad. Apple are not referring to the "blow up mode."

It is rather silly that in that particular form letter, they do not say something like: ,"You have almost certainly accidentally made your app universal instead of iPhone only" since that is the situation 100% of the time when that happens.

Good luck on waiting another 2 weeks :-/

Comment: To the genius who downvoted this: this answer is **FIVE YEARS OLD**.  Like 95% of QA on this site, it is now utterly out of date.  (Bot the question and answers.)  By all means, **go ahead and leave a note** explaining that the QA is out of date, and any further new information.  It helps future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to create a specific version of your app for the iPad, however all iPhone apps must also be able to run on the iPad. You might want to try searching google for resources on how to make your app iPad compatible.

Comment: Thanks, Now i understand, i've initiated the app as Universal- and this was wrong, what i've done is... removing the "Main NIB for Base Name (iPAD)" from the info-plist file, and the app is not looking for an iPad NIB anymore, so it load's my iPhone NIB, and it looks great with the compatibility icon X1, X2 on the iPad... Thanks!, i'll send it to apple for another review...